# generate file in a path, but sometimes got a generator returning

Tags: python, file, generator

```
def next_file(path):
    '''
    generator file in the path
    '''
    flist = os.listdir(path)
    for fname in flist:
        file_path = path + "/" + fname
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            yield file(file_path)
        else:
            yield next_file(file_path)
```

When the file is a dir, I want to recurse the function. 
But I would get a generator sometimes when I invoke next.
Is there any way, I can always get a file.

Comment: Unrelated: use `path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)` instead of `path = dirpath + "/" + filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate files, use `yield from  next_file(file_path)` instead of `yield next_file(file_path)` which produces a generator object.

On older Python versions without `yield from`, you could use an explicit `yield` loop here:

```
for f in next_file(file_path):
    yield f
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def next_file(path):
    '''
    generator file in the path
    '''
    flist = os.listdir(path)
    for fname in flist:
        file_path = path + "/" + fname
        if os.path.isfile(file_path):
            yield file(file_path)
        else:
            for f in next_file(file_path):
                yield f
```

`next_file` returns a generator, so when you do `return next_file(file_path)`, the generator returned by `next_file` is yielded (instead of value), so you need to iterate over that generator and `yield` all the elements one by one.